# ExtendedCucumberOptions from cucumber-runner is throwing Cant load plugins error

Tags: maven, selenium-webdriver, bdd, cucumber-junit

I am new to cucumber BDD, i have used ExtendedCucucmberOptions from cucumnber-runner dependency to generate better reports. When i have ran the TestRunner file as Junit , i am getting below error trace

cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Couldn't load plugin class: null

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import com.github.mkolisnyk.cucumber.runner.ExtendedCucumber;
import com.github.mkolisnyk.cucumber.runner.ExtendedCucumberOptions;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
@RunWith(ExtendedCucumber.class)
@ExtendedCucumberOptions(
jsonReport="target/cucumber.json"
,jsonUsageReport="target/cucumber-usage.json"
,usageReport=true
,detailedReport=true
,toPDF=true
,outputFolder="target"
)
@CucumberOptions(
dryRun=false,
strict=true, 
//tags={"@Test"},
features={"./src/test/resources/com/qa/features/fileupload.feature"},    
glue={"com.qa.stepdef"},
plugin={"pretty:STDOUT","html:test-output/cucumber.html"
,"json:target/cucumber.json"                               
,"usage:target/cucumber-usage.json"
,"junit:target/cucumber-results.xml"
,"rerun:target/rerun.txt"},
monochrome=true)
public class FileUploadTestRunner {}
```

[image]

Please Any help is highly appreciated.

Below is my pom xml

```
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>junit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                    <version>4.12</version>
                </dependency>

                <dependency>
                    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
                    <version>4.7.1</version>
                </dependency>

                <dependency>
                    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
                    <version>4.7.1</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
                    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
                    <version>3.5.3</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
                    <version>4.7.1</version>
                </dependency>

                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.github.mkolisnyk</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cucumber-runner</artifactId>
                    <version>1.3.5</version>
                </dependency>

                <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.freemarker/freemarker -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
                    <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3.29</version>
                </dependency>



            </dependencies>
           <plugins>
            <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.22.0</version>
                        <configuration>
                    <forkCount>2</forkCount>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*TestRunner.java</include>
                            </includes>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude> **/WebTableTestRunner.java</exclude>
                            </excludes> 


                        </configuration>
                        </plugin>
                        <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.1</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <source>1.8</source>
                            <target>1.8</target>
                            <fork>true</fork>
                            <executable>C:\Program Files 
                         (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\bin\javac</executable>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>

                </plugins>
            </build>
```

Comment: share the dependencies you are using

Comment: I have added pom content, please see